Does law apply to representations of things?
Using kosher ingredients, technics, pans and kitchen, I made a candy animal, like a chocolat rabbit.
Can a Jew eat it no matter what animal it represent?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamantash

I haven't read these but it would seem one can make animals:Rambam (Sefer HaMitzvot, Lo Taaseh 4; Mishneh Torah, Hilchot Avodah Zarah 3:11), Tosafot Yoma 54a, Shulchan Aruch (Yoreh Deah 141:6)

But you may run into problems if the animal is known to be an idol or is a bird held by a god.

If it's actually a pagan reference that's a problem; but you can totally buy a chocolate bunny that's kosher certified. (See the ingredients label for the kosher certification.) The fact that it's shaped like a non-kosher animal doesn't matter.
